# Loging from shell in Android

Tags: android-logcat

How can you log to the standard loginig system in Android from shell? The one where logcat is used to read the log. I know you can write a very simple program to do that, but isn't there one already?

Comment: You need to have android tools set in system's PATH variable and then run `adb shell logcat`. More information http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html ; or in two steps, first run `adb shell` (this will estabilish the android shell terminal) and then run `logcat`.

Comment: This gets the log. I want to write to it.

Comment: I see what you mean now (sorry, I didn't understand the question for the first time). You want to write to android system log. Seems you already figured it out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use the **log** command.

```
adb shell log "msg"
```

It is quite obvious to name the command **log**, when you think about it.